# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null when calling a port curl call

Tags: java, curl, http-post, spring-tool-suite

I have the following class:

```
    @CrossOrigin()
    @PostMapping(path = "/xcpd", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    protected String xcpd(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        JSONObject jsonData = null;
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject responseXCPD = null;
        int user_id = -1;
        int pid = -1;
        try {
            if ((jsonData = new JSONObject(getJSONString(request))) != null) {
                if (jsonData.has("country_code") && jsonData.has("identifier")) {
                    
                    // User data
                    user_id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("user_id"));
                    String rolename = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("rolename"));
                    ....
                   }
                }
         }
}
```

I'm using the following curl call to call this endpoint:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8083/xcpd -d '{"user_id":"1", 
      "country_code":"IE",
      "rolename": "doctor",
      "identifier": "1.1.1.1"
}'
```

When I call the curl example I get the error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` for this line `user_id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("user_id"));`. I suppose that means that string `user_id` is empty and can't be converted in integer.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse a null value. If you want to parse the body of the request there is a simple way to do that. In you xcpd method ad a parameter annotated with  @RequestBody and it will be automatically converted to a java object. getParameter is not the right way to get a field from a request body.
See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use your `jsonData` object to access the `user_id`.

See the part of the documentation for the getParameter method:

> For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.